# Tag for Ola Hallengren's scripts?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-creation

While I have enough rep to create a new tag, I figured this one was worth asking the community about first before creating it.

There are plenty of questions regarding Ola Hallengren's solution for database maintenance. I was wondering if it makes sense to provide a tag ola-hallengren (or something like that)? This way one could very easily locate questions related to those particular solutions. I realize this would only ever end up on questions tagged with sql-server and possibly database-maintenance. I just was curious if it made sense.

(As an afterthought....would we need his permission to make a tag after his name?)

Comment: This has been previously [discussed in meta](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/tagging-for-third-party-tools-scripts/2433#comment4116_2424)

Comment: I'm not against it, btw.

Comment: I'd second this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't have very strong feelings about this, but on balance I think **it is OK to create this tag**.

Some factors that I considered before making that statement:

- We did have an [ola-hallengren](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ola-hallengren) tag before, but as I recall it was only applied to a *very* small number of questions. It was auto-deleted when those questions were de-tagged, for whatever reason. I don't believe it was an explicit moderator- or meta-driven action. It just happened.
- We have roughly [50 well-received questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=ola+is%3Aquestion+score%3A0..+closed%3Ano) right now on this topic.
- Ola does have an account here, and has been active in the past, but not since August 2015.

  [image: profile for Ola Hallengren at Database Administrators Stack Exchange, Q&A for database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and learn from others in the community]
- Ola may find the tag useful to address [support issues](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2423/1192), which could help encourage participation.
- The tag seems useful enough for [the normal reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32041/194636).
- I don't believe we need Ola's permission to create [ola-hallengren](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ola-hallengren), but if there is objection, we can act on it accordingly.
- It might be (*warning: complete speculation!*) that the previous removal of the tag contributed to Ola's decision not to participate here as much. If so (big if), one extra tag seems a small price to pay to potentially help fix that.

If you do decide to add the tag, please do so in small batches (say 5 at a time) with a decent gap in between to avoid flooding the home page with modified questions.

Comment: A nice reply Paul.